# Ajax-call not fired ONCE after onclick='window.open(...)'

Tags: ajax, primefaces, window.open, selectonemenu

A choice on p:selectOneMenu will update the screen_prop panel with screen name and screen thumbnail. But the ajax update for screen_prop stops to work ONCE after the h:graphicImage is clicked, which fires a window.open to show an image in a new tab.

Both screenBean and pageBean do have SessionScoped.

Any ideas on what's happened?
Thank you.

```
<p:panelGrid id="panel">
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="screen_selection" value="#{screenBean.selectedScreenId}">
            <f:selectItems 
                value="#{pageBean.screenIds}" var="scr"
                itemLabel="#{scr.name}" itemValue="#{scr.id}" />
            <p:ajax
                update=":screen_prop"
                listener="#{pageBean.handleSelection}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
</panelGrid>

<panelGrid id="screen_prop">
    <h:outputText id="screen_name" value="#{screenBean.selectedScreenName}"/>

    <h:graphicImage
        value="#{screenBean.getThumbnail(screen.id)}"
        onclick="window.open('screenshot.xhtml?screen_id=#{screen.id}'); return false" />
</panelGrid>
```

Comment: Hi, with or without the "return false". It doesn't work properly :( I tried yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that i have to change the param's value of **com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews** to a higher number to solve the problem. I hope to help someone out, who has the same problem :)